# Underscore.js _.tap() function what is a method chain?

Tags: javascript, underscore.js, chaining, method-chaining

The Underscore.js documentation explains that the `_.tap()` function  "taps" into a method chain. http://underscorejs.org/#tap

I have trouble following their example:

```
_.chain([1,2,3,200])
  .filter(function(num) { return num % 2 == 0; })
  .tap(alert)
  .map(function(num) { return num * num })
  .value();
=> // [2, 200] (alerted)
=> [4, 40000]
```

What is the method chain in this context? I always thought of method chaining as the concept of chaining methods off of one another: `object.foo().bar().baz()`.

I have seen examples using this method: `module.exports = _.tap {}, (connectors) ->`, so does this "tap" into the object literal's method chain?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

From the [fine manual](http://underscorejs.org/#chaining):

> **Chaining**
>   [...]
>   Calling **chain** will cause all future method calls to return wrapped objects. When you've finished the computation, use **value** to retrieve the final value.

So chaining in the Underscore context is the same as chaining elsewhere except that you're chaining Underscore methods on a wrapped object. You start by calling `_.chain` to get your wrapper:

```
_(obj).chain()
```

then you call Underscore methods on what `_.chain` returns and they will return wrapped objects as well:

```
_(obj).chain()
      .filter(function(x) { ... })
      .map(function(x) { ... })
      ...
```

and finally you call `_.value` to unwrap the chaining-wrapper:

```
var result = _(obj).chain()
                   .filter(function(x) { ... })
                   .map(function(x) { ... })
                   ...
                   .value();
```

Back to `_.tap`. All [`tap` does is this](https://github.com/jashkenas/underscore/blob/1.5.2/underscore.js#L867):

```
_.tap = function(obj, interceptor) {
  interceptor(obj);
  return obj;
};
```

so it calls the passed function, `interceptor` on the value being iterated over and returns what is being iterated over without doing anything to it. `_.tap` is the same as:

```
.map(function(x, func) { func(x); return x })
```

but it makes your intention clear. In effect, `_.tap` lets you peek into the data passing through the method chain without altering that data.

Comment: Could you please clarify what you mean by `wrapped object`? An object literal `{ obj }` ?

Comment: Saying `_.chain(x)` or `_(x).chain()` gives you `x` wrapped inside another object the supports the Underscore functions. Then each Underscore function recognizes that it is dealing with a wrapped object and maintains the wrapper for the next step in the chain..

Answer (score 9):

I agree the example in the docs is stupid as `alert`ing the iterated object is never something you'd want to do in a real situation (unless you were debugging and wanted to know the state of the object between 2 chained methods — but in this scenario it would probably just alert `[object Object]`; `console.log` would be more appropriate but wouldn't work as intended [but I digress]). Here's an example of a non-chaining workflow:

```
var x = { a: 1, b: 2, c: 3 };

x = _.filter( x, function( value ){
  return ( value % 2 === 0 );
} );

x.length = _.size( x );

x = _.pairs( x );
```

This scenario really lends itself to chaining: all the code above is essentially creating and serially modifying one object. Chaining makes that clear, and stops you continuously writing assignments. The only problem is the line where I declare `length` — that doesn't fit neatly into the chain, since it's the only statement there that's not simply running an underscore method on the object and assigning the result back to that object. And this is where `tap` comes in: you want to do something that doesn't lend itself easily to chaining within the chain. Here's how he chained workflow looks:

```
var x = _
  .chain( { a: 1, b: 2, c: 3 } )
  .filter( function( value ){
    return ( value % 2 === 0 );
  } )
  .tap( function( x ){
    x.length = _.size( x );
  } )
  .pairs()
  .value();
```

Comment: Thanks Barney, this answer was also helpful in my understanding.  I am accepting muistooshort's answer as his was first.

Answer (score 1):

Method chaining, as you describe, chains methods off each other.  The key detail, with regard to `_.tap` is that **the results of each method are passed on to the next**.

**_.tap lets you insert a method whose results aren't passed through**.  The result of the previous method is passed in to the method following `_tap`. This allows for processing of intermediate results within a chain without changing the results of the chain.

In your example the `alert` would break the chain if called alone, since it doesn't return anything.  Using `_.tap`, causes the results of the previous method (`filter(function(num) { return num % 2 == 0; })`) to be passed through to the following method (`map(function(num) { return num * num })`)

Answer (score 1):

The chain in your example is `filter().tap().map()`:

- `_.chain([1,2,3,300])` wraps an array in an underscore wrapper that has methods like `filter`, `tap`, `map`, `value`, etc.
- `.tap(alert)` unwraps the result from `filter()`, calls `alert()` with the unwrapped object, and then wraps it up again and returns it
- `.value()` returns the wrapped object (minus the wrapper).